# Finding Number of Nonzero eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is a $3\times3$ non-zero matrix such that $A^2=0$.
To find number of non-zero eigenvalues of $A$.
How to approach? If you can suggest a good easy to understand study material that would be really helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? What are [your thoughts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)? Please, help us help you by letting us know what you know and where you're stuck.

Comment: @Arthur I feel like det(A) = 0, as det(A^2)=0, so there is one eigen value which is equals to zero. But I'm not sure

Comment: There is _at least_ one eigenvalue which is equal to $0$ from that argument. And it can't be 3, since $A \neq 0$. That leaves either $1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after searching here and there I have a conclusion that A has **no Nonzero eigenvalues.**

AX=CX
=> (A^2)X=(C^2)X

Now A^2=0,
So C^2=0, i.e. C=0

Can anyone confirm?